# How to link from a specific column on a table to another specific column on another table in a database?

Tags: mysql

I am quite new to PHP and MySQL and I will love it if anyone here can be of help to me.
I have written some code to echo out Topics created by users from a table (`TOPICS`) and post it on a page. I also created another table (`CONTENT`).  But my main problem is how to link that `TOPIC` to another column in another table in the same database. I have tried this on my own but once I click on Topics, it just echoes out everything in the other table (`CONTENT`) but I want a single `TOPIC` linked to a single `CONTENT`.

How do I do this?

Comment: You shoud look at foreign key/references in mysql, in the SQL documentation.

Comment: You should post the structure of the tables and the query you're using to get the data.

Answer (score 0):

This is a basic operation known as JOIN.

You don't indicate which columns exist in each table, but you should probably be doing something like:

```
SELECT C.*, T.*
  FROM Content AS C
  JOIN Topics  AS T ON C.TopidID = T.ID;
```

You can then add a WHERE clause to filter the list down to the content records that you are interested in.